# Android TextView Text doesn't appear

Tags: android, textview

I have written a text view with,

```
textView.setMovementMethod(new ScrollingMovementMethod());
int gravity = 0;
gravity |= Gravity.CENTER_HORIZONTAL;
gravity |= Gravity.TOP;
textView.setGravity(gravity);
```

But when I run the app, the text doesn't appear. Then I tried applying a background color to the text view to make sure it's rendering. Yes. I can see the textView background though the text doesn't appear.

Moreover changing center_horizontal gravity to left/right or setting horizontalScrolling of the view to false can fix the issue. But in this particular scenario, I need to have center_horizontal gravity and horizontal scrolling as well.

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: to where you are adding this text

Comment: You need to share your complete code with Question,where you are adding  text in your textview

Comment: maybe you gave too much padding in xml file

Comment: You need to share your XML file code

Comment: No. I'm using all the elements written in java without using any XML layouts. So, I'm sure it doesn't have any padding issues. Surprisingly when I drag the mouse over the text, the text starts to appear.

Comment: You need to add layout params

Comment: we can't GUESS.

Comment: Try using set textColor of the TextView